# How to store kinesis video stream into S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-kinesis

I'm sending live video streaming to amazon console by kinesis video streaming, now i want to store it into amazon S3. How to store it into S3 please explain in detail. Thanks

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to use Amazon Kinesis Video to store the video into Amazon S3? Are you not able to directly store it in S3?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein How you can stream the video to S3? I don't think you can do that in realtime! from your mobile phone camera to S3 directly?

Comment: @Soliman Amazon S3 is a storage system. You can 'upload' data to S3 to store as an object. While it does not accept standard streaming protocols, you could simply store raw video in the object. If you wish to store data from a streaming format, take a look at [How to Send Live Video to AWS Elemental MediaStore | AWS Media Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/part1-how-to-send-live-video-to-aws-elemental-mediastore/).

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Kinesis Video does not store videos in S3 "out-of-the-box". The intention is to provide a service that allows videos to be *processed* in some manner.

[image: Amazon Kinesis Video]

You can write a consumer app that will store the video into Amazon S3, but frankly there are easier ways to store the data in S3 (such as directly storing it S3 rather than sending it via Kinesis).

Picture is from: [Amazon Kinesis Video Streams: How It Works - Amazon Kinesis Video Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/how-it-works.html)

Comment: I want to send and save video to Amazon S3 in real time! do i have any other option than kinesis video stream? I want to store video to perform data analytics on it later. How to store live video directly into S3? Thanks

Comment: Can you simply save the data into an Amazon S3 object? You say that you want to do it in real time, but will you be immediately using the video? Why do you need it in real time? And is it enough just to save the file in real time by using a multi-part upload?

Comment: @MuhammadSannan Kinesis Video also provides data retention which means you can use Kinesis Video not only to ingest and consume but also to store video for long time. Currently it supports max data retention of 10 years. Also you can retrieve the data whenever you want using `GetMedia` or HLS/DASH APIs

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I have a similar use case: I want to record video from web clients but I don't know when recording ends and webapp is closed, so I need to send the video chunks in real time.
Which aws service architecture do you recommend for this?

Comment: @tomeraz Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment in an old question. Questions that ask for recommendations sometimes get closed on StackOverflow, so you might want to try asking on https://www.reddit.com/r/aws.