# Streaming media to files in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, aws-sdk

## My problem:

I want to stream media I record on the client (typescript code) to my AWS storage (services like YouTube / Twitch / Zoom / Google Meet can live record and save the record to their cloud. Some of them even have host-failure tolerance and create a file if the host has disconnected).
I want each stream to have a different file name so future triggers will be available from it.

I tried to save the stream into S3, but maybe there are more recommended storage solutions for my problems.

### What services I tried:

1. **S3**: I tried to stream directly into S3 but it doesn't really support updating files.
   I tried multi-part files but they are not host-failure tolerance.
   I tried to upload each part and have a lambda to merge it (yes, it is very dirty and consuming) but I sometimes had ordering problems.
2. **Kinesis-Video**: I tried to use kinesis-video but couldn't enable the saving feature with the SDK.
   By hand, I saw it saved a new file after a period of time or after a size was reached so maybe it is not my wanted solution.
3. **Amazon IVS**: I tried it because Twitch recommended this although it is way over my requirements.
   I couldn't find an example of what I want to do in code with SDK (only by hand examples).

### Questions

1. Do I look at the right services?
2. What can I do with the AWS-SDK to make it work?
3. Is there a good place with code examples for future problems? Or maybe a way to search for solutions?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987620/how-to-store-kinesis-video-stream-into-s3-bucket